# How do I manually edit the custom and application Dictionary entries in Visual Studio Code IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need some assistance with removing entries that I accidentally added to the dictionaries while playing with VS Code.

Am completely new to this IDE and am looking for where I can manually remove words that I entered into the VS Code User Dictionary as well as the Application Dictionary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found part of my answer for the workspace words.

**File > Settings**

Click on **Workspace**

Scroll down to *Extensions > Code Spell Checker*
[image: Settings]

Still looking for the User words

Comment: New to VSCode. There in the above image captured there are [User | Workspace]. If an item is in the list mouse over the word and you are given the option to delete it.